# api call within ngFor in Angular6

Tags: angular

I am using `angular6` to create a single page application to display some info that require two `api` calls

**First call:**

```
GET /getInfo
```

> Response:[{id: 111, name: jack, phone: 123456789}, .....]

**Second call:**

```
GET /available?id (takes the id get from the first request)
```

> Response:{status: available}

What I do is to make the first call in ngOnInit() and make the second in loop

However, when I get the id inside ngFor and want to make the second call, if I call the function within ngFor, the api will get called very often. Are there any way to avoid this? or any better way to make the second call?

Comment: Have you looked at the angular documentation, specifically the tutorial? BTW angular6 should not be tagged as angularjs - it should be tagged as straight angular.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks for the response! I did watch many documents today, what I did is to make the first api call under ngOnInit() and try to call the second api call inside ngFor loop. However, the second call will keep repeating.

Comment: In that case you need to edit your question to show what you have tried - otherwise its too general a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Assuming that you have two service methods, and a class defined for each of their return values, e.g.:

```
export class Info {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
}

export class Availability {
 status: string;
}

getInfo(): Observable<Info> {
  return this.http.get<Info>("http://myservice.com/info");
}

getStatus(info: Info): Observable<Availability> {
  return this.http.get<Status>("http://myservice.com/available?id=" + info.id);
}
```

then you would do this:

```
 getAvailability(): Observable<Availability> {
    return this.getInfo().pipe(
       mergeMap(info => getStatus(info))
    );
  }
```

Comment: I do have those service method, but may I know when to call the second service, since I dont want and button to trigger it(directly list out all the info). Sorry I am quiet new to Angular.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  Please show us what you have tried so far, maybe we can get an idea of what you're trying to do.